# Why does Jupyter Lab install fail without Rust?

Tags: python, pip, jupyter-lab

I'm using MBA M2 macOS 13.2.1, and installing Jupyter Lab using pip worked last night:

```
pip install jupyterlab
```

Then I did a clean maintenance reinstall (`pip freeze | xargs pip uninstall -y -q && pip install -U -r .requirements.txt && jupyter lab clean --all; jupyter lab build`).

Suddenly when I install Jupyter Lab with pip as above, I get

```
Collecting y-py<0.6.0,>=0.5.3
  Using cached y_py-0.5.4.tar.gz (39 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [6 lines of output]
      
      Cargo, the Rust package manager, is not installed or is not on PATH.
      This package requires Rust and Cargo to compile extensions. Install it through
      the system's package manager or via https://rustup.rs/
      
      Checking for Rust toolchain....
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
```

Do I really now need to install Rust in order to get Jupyter working (and if so why is this not mentioned in the installation instructions)?

Comment: Just tried it on Mac OS X and didn't need rust. What platform are you on? I can see this being necessary if `pip` doesn't already have binaries for that platform.

Comment: @kindall MBA M2 macOS 13.2.1, and it worked last night. All I did was a clean maintenance reinstall (`pip freeze | xargs pip uninstall -y -q && pip install -U -r .requirements.txt && jupyter lab clean --all; jupyter lab build`)

Comment: Which version of python are you using?

Comment: oh never mind my comment. I didn't notice it was a full build. mine got stuck on Node since I didn't have that installed already. so yeah, there are some prerequisites apparently...

Comment: @kindall New prerequisites? I've been using 3.6.1 without issues before this.

Comment: See [this particular post here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/jupyter-lab-install-fails-without-rust/18065/8?u=fomightez) by davidbrochart, where this was crossposted [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/jupyter-lab-install-fails-without-rust/18065?u=fomightez).